# How can I run power to my shed from my pool electrical panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, shed

I have a single 15 amp breaker available in my pool electrical panel.  I would like to run power from there to my shed for a handful of outlets and a pair of light fixtures.  I plan to bury metal conduit 6" deep, but beyond that I'm unsure what is required.  Do I need a subpanel or disconnect in the shed?  What size and quantity of wires would be required in the conduit?  The shed is about 45 ft from the pool panel.  Do I need a grounding electrode at the shed?  This is in the state of Georgia, USA.

Comment: How many square feet is this shed?  How much unused ampacity is available on the pool feeder?

Comment: The shed is 176 sq ft (16x11).  The feeder to the pool control box comes from a sub panel (fed from the meter box) with a 40A double pole breaker.  Inside the pool control box there are two 20A double pole breakers, two 20A single pole breakers and two 15A single pole breakers, one of which is the spare that I would like to use.

Comment: How much load is currently placed on the feeder?

Comment: The pool pump motor is rated at 9.7A max load @ 230V

Comment: Is that the only load on the feeder currently, or are there other loads present as well?

Comment: Sorry, hit enter before the comment was finished.  There is a blower for the spa which is 230V and 5.5A.  The gas heater control is on a 20A breaker, but probably doesn't draw much current.  The pool control panel itself is on a 15A breaker.  The biggest current draw there would be the chlorinator cell with a max of 5A.  The other 15A breaker is for the pool light and a GFCI spare receptacle on the outside of the box.  The current rating for the light is 2.5A-5.4A  depending on the model.  I'm not sure which one I have.  I can dig up the paperwork if necessary.

Comment: If you can dig up the current rating for the light, that'd be great...

Comment: There are two lights, both 120V.  One is 95 W, the other is 40 W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Go ahead, but make sure to get the details right

Since you are pulling 25A (out of the 40A total available) on the pool feeder right now, you can route a single 20A/120V circuit (using 12/2 W/G UF or 12AWG THWN hot/neutral/ground in the conduit) from the pool subpanel's spare breaker to a disconnect at the shed (any standard A/C disconnect box will do the job happily), then you can wire the shed lights and receptacles to the disconnect box as they won't consume but a fraction of the remaining 15A normally.

You won't need a full subpanel at the shed since you're feeding it with a single branch circuit, nor will you need a grounding electrode as you are installing a disconnect for a single circuit, not a feeder and subpanel. (This is per the exception to 250.32(A).)